# Performance of Ransack in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

Ransack did a awesome to let us do custom search easily in rails even the popular backend active_admin is using it. However, these are all the goods..

Anyone can advice what's the performance or drawback for using it? such as the performance when large data? or are there something not easily customisable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ransack really is only another layer of abstraction between your database and your logic, so there really are no notable drawbacks to use it.
Basically anything that your database would be good at, Ransack will do fine and vice-versa.

For "large data", it depends how large means for you, but as long as you can use indexes to speed up your queries, it should be fine for most web applications use cases.
However, things can become quite slow for full text search, if you use Ransack features such as `name_cont`, which is translated to `ILIKE` with two wildcards. In such a case, index will not help you and therefore these kind of query can become really slow on large data set. Depending on the SQL server you are using, some full-text search features could however help improving performances. Anyway, as I said above, this is more an SQL specific issue, and is not directly related to Ransack.

Unless you are really sure SQL will not be good enough for your use case, if Ransack fits your needs, my suggestion would be to go with it, and to worry about performance when you are sure it will become a bottleneck.

> premature optimization is the root of all evil